# Template symbol search issue

Tags: c++

I have an issue with templates I can't really understand.

File 1:

```
namespace A
{

template <typename T>
void foo(T value)
{
    ...
}

} // A
```

File 2:

```
namespace B
{

template <typename Type>
class Object
{
    ...

void bar(const Object& other)
{
    ...
    B::foo(other);
    ...
}
    ...
};

template <typename Type>
void foo(Object<Type> value)
{
    ...
}

} // B
```

In general: I have template function in one namespace, and specialized function in other (A::foo and B::foo).
If I try to compile it as in snippets above, then it fails, as it can't find
proper foo function. That is ok.
But if I remove namespace resolution before foo call, then it compiles and (!!!) it calls proper B::foo function. How can it be?
I checked on both gcc and clang.

Comment: Specializations should appear in the same namespace as their templates

Comment: It's not a specialization, it's a separate overload.

Comment: Please create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove the `B::` qualification, the call `foo(object)` can find `B::foo` through [Argument-Dependent Lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (ADL).

ADL is used for function calls which use an unqalified function name, and searches namespaces associated with types of the arguments in the function call. Since `object` is of type `Object` which is in namespace `B`, then `B` is searched by ADL and `B::foo` is found.

The remaining question is why the lookup of `foo` is postponed until instantiation, while that of `B::foo` is not. The reason is there's an explicit rule in the standard for that (C++14 14.6.2/1). Inside a template, a function call using an *unqualified* name for the function is left unresolved until instantiation if any of the arguments depend on template parameters. That is indeed your case, since `object` is of type `Object<Type>`, so it depends on the template paremeter `Type`.

Comment: Thank you for complete answer.